# How to fix concurrency issue with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, dictionary, concurrency, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

Serial function working differently than similarly designed parallel function

```
def update(sharedDict,node,...):
for neighbor in weightNode:
    sharedDict[neighbor] += *positive float(0->1)
sharedDict[node] += *positive float(0->1)
```

This is the slave function of each process. Each addition is a positive float unaffected by any value in sharedDict is added. No keys are added.

```
def pSerial(graph):
... #setup left out for readability
for i in range(100):
    last_serialDict = serialDict
    serialDict = dict.fromkeys(last_serialDict.keys(),0.0)

    s = *positive float(0->1) #used in later *positive float
    for node in serialDict:
        for neighbor in wDigraph[node]:
            serialDict[neighbor] += *positive float(0->1)
        serialDict[node] += *positive float(0->1)
    
    err = sum([abs(serialDict[node] - last_serialDict[node]) for node in serialDict])
    if err < nodeCount * 0.000001:
        return serialDict
raise RuntimeError('failed to converge in 100 iterations')
```

This is the serial implementation of the algorithm. Note that the slave function is identical to the nested for loop.

```
def pParallel(graph):
... #setup left out for readability
with Manager() as manager:
    parallelDict = dict(dict.fromkeys(wDigraph, 1.0 / nodeCount)) #from weighted graph
    
    for i in range(100):
        lastParallel = parallelDict
        parallelDict = dict.fromkeys(lastParallel.keys(),0.0)
    
        s = *positive float(0->1)
    
        pool = Pool() 
        sharedDict = manager.dict(parallelDict)
        pool.starmap(update, [(sharedDict,node,...) for node in parallelDict])
        
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        
        parallelDict = dict(sharedDict)

        err = sum([abs(parallelDict[node] - lastParallel[node]) for node in parallelDict])
        if err < nodeCount * 0.000001:
            return parallelDict
raise RuntimeError('failed to converge in 100 iterations')
```

With this function computing the PageRank of variable size graphs in parallel, the update function not only is slower than the serial version(programmed the same way) but also does not converge in the same amount of iterations(concurrency issue)

What is the issue with the code that is causing this?

Comment: Maybe share your serialized vs parallel version, that may make the issue more clear.  As it is the code sample you posted appears to be incomplete, and as a result a bit hard to follow.

Comment: The pool.starmap function returns an iterator and you're not using it.  If you used it, you would be shipping only the results of function calls between processes.  You could keep parallelDict in the main process and update it there.  As it is, I think you are continually shipping the entire dictionary between processes (Managers exchange data between processes, so they aren't necessarily efficient).  Perhaps if you shared more of the program we could form a better idea of how it works.

Comment: @monkut I updated the Code Snippet

Comment: @PaulCornelius I initially used the iterator returned by the star map, however, it produced a dictionary of the updated dictionaries for each process of the mapping - which makes sense. The max length of the dictionary is around 60-150, so although the shipping may cause some lag it should not be slowing down by 10-15x of the serial implementation, right? Also I updated the Code Snippet.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Also, it would be ideal to keep the parallelDict in main to avoid costs, but how do you do that in parallel?

Comment: There is no way to update a dictionary "in parallel."  You can't write two things to the same dictionary at the same time; it's a single data structure.  Beside, dictionaries are highly optimized in Python since they are literally used everywhere - every object stores its member variables in a dictionary (`__dict__`).  Don't worry about performance of a 150 item dictionary.

Comment: In your code you are launching 400 different Processes (4 Processes, 100 loop iterations).  That involves operating system overhead.  For each function evaluation, Python will serialize the arguments and serialize the returned values.  The calculation, as you have shown it, looks rather trivial - one multiplication per item.  It would not surprise me that the overhead of launching/closing processes, serializing/ deserializing data structures, far outweighs the benefit of parallelization.  Have you timed the performance of your functions?  Why do you think multiprocessing is necessary here?

Comment: @PaulCornelius I think I see what you meant by keeping the sharedDict as just a normal dictionary in the main process. I am surprised by this only because I simply did not understand the purpose of the DictProxy and Manager().dict because when reading the documentation, I found: `A proxy is an object which refers to a shared object which lives (presumably) in a different process.` It was my understanding that the Proxy object was a different mutable in each process but somehow combined later by the interpreter.

Comment: @PaulCornelius I have tested the performance of my serial function, however, the parallel function has not converged. The serial function when compared to a `networkx` serial function, worked well until around 1000 nodes and 500 edges per node. The main focus is to analyze the parallel speed-up of the serial algorithm (even though I said the limit was 60-150) in graphs containing up to 100 thousand nodes and several dozen edges per node. This whole process is simply illustrating to me that I may have designed the parallel algorithm incorrectly.

Comment: I think your last comment is on the right track.  Multiprocessing doesn't work well when you have to move a lot of data between Processes.  It is great when you have relatively small pieces of data and a lot of number crunching to do on each piece.  So I agree that algorithm design is most likely your way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not safe to update the same dict in parallel** from multiple processes/threads. This cause a **race condition**. The threads needs to write in different places so to avoid this (they can read the same part safely though). Adding new key or removing existing ones to the same shared dict also cause a race condition due to the key that needs to be possibly re-hashed internally.